# Which JSON method is better practice to use: Get() or GetValue()?

Tags: json, c++builder-10.1-berlin

Given the following two lines of code produce the same output, which of the two methods is better practice?

```
TJSONArray *resultsArray = (TJSONArray*) response->Get("results")->JsonValue;

TJSONArray *resultsArray = (TJSONArray*) response->GetValue("results");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetValue()` is functionally the same as calling `Get()->JsonValue`, but with an extra check to make sure the requested key actually exists before accessing its `JsonValue`.

`TJSONObject` has a protected [`GetPairByName()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.GetPairByName) method, which returns a pointer to the `TJSONPair` object of the requested key if found, or `NULL` if the key is not found.

`Get()` simply calls `GetPairByName()` and returns the pointer as-is:

```pascal
function TJSONObject.Get(const Name: string): TJSONPair;
begin
  Result := GetPairByName(Name);
end;
```

If you know for sure that the key exists, using `Get()->JsonValue` is perfectly safe. But, if there is any possibility that the key may not exist, you need to check the return value for `NULL` before accessing any of the `TJSONPair`'s members.

`GetValue()` calls `GetPairByName()` and returns the `JsonValue` of the returned `TJSONPair` only if the key is found, otherwise it returns `NULL`:

```pascal
function TJSONObject.GetValue(const Name: string): TJSONValue;
var
  LPair: TJSONPair;
begin
  LPair := GetPairByName(Name);
  if LPair <> nil then
    Result := LPair.JSONValue
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

If there is any possibility that the key may not exist, it is cleaner to call `GetValue()` instead of `Get()->JsonValue`.